# Selecting all dropdowns

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

Inside my form, I've declared dropdows the following way:

```
Html.DropDownList(String.Format("Record[{0}].Action", i), new[]
{
    new SelectListItem { Text="Ajustar Quantidade", Value= ((int)InventoryGoodsActionEnum.AdjustQuantity).ToString()},
    new SelectListItem { Text="Relocalizar", Value= ((int)InventoryGoodsActionEnum.AdjustLocation).ToString(), Selected=true},
    new SelectListItem { Text="Ajustar Quantidade e Relocalizar", Value= ((int)InventoryGoodsActionEnum.AdjustQuantityLocation).ToString()},
    new SelectListItem { Text="Ignorar", Value= ((int)InventoryGoodsActionEnum.Ignore).ToString()},
})
```

Now I'd like to be able to get all of them (they will be multiple because the id increases) with jquery so I can iterate through them.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [tag/element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) and an attribute [starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), like this:

```
$("select[name^='Record[']")each(function() {
  //do something
});
```

This will select all dropdowns with a `name="Record[...."` to loop through.  If necessary you can add a [ends-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) as well, like this:

```
$("select[name^='Record['][name$='].Action']")each(function() {
  //do something
});
```

Comment: Thanks Nick. While you were answering, I came up with a different approach which worked as well but yours is more correct.
This was my approach:
$("input[id|=Record],[id$=Action]")

Comment: @Hallaghan - Ah yes, that's a different starts with, either way works :) Your .DropDownList is rendering as an `<input>` though? It should be a `<select>`, or I may be going crazy...

Comment: @Hallaghan - Are you sure you're not using `":input"`? :)